# Refresh a listbox's datasource

Tags: c#, refresh, datasource

I have a form for my update method, the form is in detail view. Next to the textboxes I have a listbox which shows the names of all the names in the database table. Under the listbox I also have an extra textbox to quick search the name in case user would like to type it in.

When I go to update one of the names, such as changing John to Jonathan, the database updates with the new name as I have checked on sql server, but the name in the listbox does not change! There's a dirty way to fix this by moving the position the listbox is selected on currently to movefirst(). However, under the listbox I have the textbox which is a quick search as I've mentioned, so I go to type Jonathan in the search text box, but nothing appears. However, if I type the former name John, then I get the details of this row in the table.

Is there a way I can fix this?

UPDATE 1:

Ive tried making the listbox datasource null then reassigning it again but it doesen't work. Ive put my code for my update form below.

---

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class updateContact : Form
    {
        public updateContact()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void updateContact_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'tblcontactsupdate.tblContacts' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.tblContactsTableAdapter.Fill(this.tblcontactsupdate.tblContacts);
    }
    private void btnUpdateContact_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x;

        Program.da.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("Update tblContacts SET FIRSTNAME = @FIRSTNAME, LASTNME = @LASTNME WHERE ID = @ID", Program.cs);
        Program.da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@FIRSTNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = fIRSTNAMETextBox.Text;
        Program.da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@LASTNME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lASTNMETextBox.Text;
        Program.da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = iDTextBox.Text;

        Program.cs.Open();
        x = Program.da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Program.cs.Close();

        if (x >= 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record(s) has been updated");
            Program.ds.Clear();
            Program.da.Fill(Program.ds);
            txtfindUpdatecontact.Text = "";
            //lbupdateContact.DataSource = null;
            //lbupdateContact.DataSource = this.tblcontactsupdate.tblContacts;
        }       
    }
    private void txtfindUpdatecontact_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!txtfindUpdatecontact.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            this.tblContactsBindingSource.Filter = "FIRSTNAME = '" + txtfindUpdatecontact.Text + "'";

        }
        else
        {
            this.tblContactsBindingSource.RemoveFilter();
        }
    }

    private void lbupdateContact_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void iDTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void fIRSTNAMETextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void lASTNMETextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to set the `DataSource` of your listbox one more time after updating the source.

Something like below: It's my data:

```
 public class Person
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyDataSource
    {
        public static List<Person> Persons = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person{Age=30,Name="Ram"},
            new Person{Age=33,Name="Rahim"},
        };
    }
```

then in the form's constructor you can do:

```
 listBox1.DataSource = MyDataSource.Persons;
 listBox1.DisplayMember = "Age";
```

then for updation, something like below:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyDataSource.Persons[0].Age = 45;
            listBox1.DataSource = null;
            listBox1.DataSource = MyDataSource.Persons;
            listBox1.DisplayMember = "Age";
        }
```

This is just an example change code according to your need.

Comment: Not sure why u have created a person object class for a database, is it a practise u should do even with databases i have learnt about OOP. but this is the first time im doing a project on my own to learn databases. So for example i have a contacts table in my database, should i create a contacts class? and list all the members how would this class link to my sql database contact table tho?

Comment: This is just an example to imagine a dummy database, depends on your need , there are many technologies which tackle this automatically and it's called ORM (Object Relation Mapping), Entity Framework is one of them

Answer (score 1):

If your DataSource is a DataTable, all you have to do is calling AcceptChanges(), like this:

```
listBox.DataSource = null;  
((DataTable)listBox.DataSource).AcceptChanges();
```